# code was working, but suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, foreach, fopen, nested-loops

This code opens a text file, then checks to see if each word in the text file
Exists in a another large 2MB dictionary file.

If it does exist, it stores the line from the dictionary file into a variable.

The code was working, but then began to generate Server 500 errors, and now
It only lists about 7 matches and then loads nothing forever.

It used to list the 1000's of matches and then stop.

```
$file_handle = fopen("POSdump.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);

   $words= explode(" ", $line ); 

   foreach ($words as $word) {

       $word = preg_replace('#[^\w+>\s\':-]#', ' ', $word);                

       $subwords= explode(" ", $word );

       $rawword = $subwords[0];   
       $poscode = $subwords[1];
       $rawword = strtoupper($rawword);       


             $handle = fopen("dictionary.txt","r"); // 

             if ($handle) {
               while (!feof($handle)) 
                           {
                      $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); 

                        if (preg_match('#\b'.$rawword.'\b#',$buffer)) {


                        echo $rawword;
            echo "</br>";


                 }
             }
         }
     }
}

?>
```

Comment: What changed between 'working and not working'?

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the file when you are done.

Comment: I knew it! Those nested file operations are mangling the server.

Comment: working meant it was listing all the files found and completing the operation.

Comment: not working meant it lists about 7 files then dies in a loop which never finishes loading, or it gives a internal server error 500

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a memory_limit error. use ini_set('memory_limit', -1) before starting the process.